# Creating a contact in Blackberry 10 from Android port

Tags: android, blackberry-10

So I am porting an Android app to Blackberry 10 and everything is going well. But I am having a problem with the "Add Contact" functionality. I have a button that takes information about a company and adds that information to a contact intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);

intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, provider.getOrganizationName());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, provider.getPhoneNumber());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, provider.getAddressLine1() + " " + provider.getAddressLine2() + " " + provider.getCity() + " " + provider.getProvince() + " " + provider.getPostalCode());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, provider.geteMail());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, provider.getOrganizationName());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, provider.getPhoneNumber());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL, provider.getAddressLine1() + " " + provider.getAddressLine2() + " " + provider.getCity() + " " + provider.getProvince() + " " + provider.getPostalCode());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL, provider.geteMail());
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.EMAIL_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK);
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this functionality working on Blackberry? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i am facing the same issue, did you managed to solve the issue ?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't made any progress on this issue. Sorry.

Comment: np thanks, i found out that it was blocked by rim in BB 10 purposely but is now working fine in BB 10.2 !!

Comment: O ok. That's great to hear. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the documents that describe Android features that are not supported by the BlackBerry Runtime for Android apps on BlackBerry 10. =)

[Unsupported APIs for BlackBerry 10](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_overview.html)

[Intents](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_blackberry10_intents.html):

> Invoking some device settings is not supported
>       android.settings.ADD_ACCOUNT_SETTINGS